# How to display user message outside partial refresh in XPages

Tags: ajax, xpages, partial-refresh

I have a panel that contain a link in XPages, the link do a partial refresh on the panel.
if the link action is successful I want to display a message to the user outside of the panel.

how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not use onComplete?

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"refreshMode="partial"refreshId="YOURCURRENTPANEL">
<xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:2NDPANEL}")]]></xp:this.onComplete>
```

The 2nd panel could contain your message to the user, maybe with visible code based on a requestScope variable you set also during the onComplete? (Better ways to do this, but you get the idea?)

Answer (score 4):

On a couple occasions, I’ve used a technique like this to have messages coming back from a server call appear as on-page notifications:

https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/76483656EE4A797B85257D1D00552CF1

You can use that route with the shipped-with-the-server Dojo control:

https://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/a-control-for-dojox.widget.toaster

Answer (score 1):

How about dGrowl messages? https://xcellerant.net/dgrowl-in-xpages/ and there is a NotesIn9 on this.

Comment: I would suggest providing Growl the Java way. You can also call it SSJS ofcourse https://elstarit.nl/?p=143